# NPM Install failing with Python is not set from command line or npm configuration

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am running npm install on my NodeJS project but installation is failing with "Python is not set from command line or npm configuration" error. No where we are using python.

Can anyone help here.

Comment: There are dependencies which use python, so while running npm install maybe there is a package using python

Comment: can you show us package.json?